# Taskbar broken in Window 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Hi my taskbar is broken and I have no idea how to fix it. I tried to move it, lock it, unlock it and everything I can but I can't find a way to repeair it.

By the way, the taskbar is not locked it's just a glitch...

[image: Taskbar broken]

**EDIT**

I tried to find a way to restore it with registry and have done alot of Google / SuperUser / MS search to find a way. I think I'm the only one on earth wich have this problem...

Here's a new image after a reboot :

[image]

Comment: Its not clickable because there isn't anything clickable to click on?

Comment: are the dotted areas not draggable? They should be.

Comment: What research have you done to try to figure out what the problem is and how to resolve it?  If you're starting here instead of starting with researching the problem through Microsoft or Google, then you're starting your problem solving efforts in the wrong place.  Aside from that, have you tried rebooting?  Sometimes Microsoft interfaces just go wonky and need a reboot.

Comment: @Tetsujin No it's not, I posted a new pic after a reboot.

Comment: @killermist I can post at Microsoft too. I've done at least 3 hours of googling for that so I think I can post a question now.

Comment: @L105 - usually, these cases are not directly linked to Windows.

Comment: @L105 What I was trying to get at, and maybe I missed, is that this question did/does not show research effort.  You now say you did research.  OK.  What terms?  Where?  This was asked an hour ago here.  How many hours have been spent elsewhere before this?  I'm not trying to say, "You're full of crap."  I'm trying to draw out stuff that others would find useful in trying to start finding a solution and determine we're not wasting time finding something that you wouldn't bother sharing later (which is common knowledge elsewhere).  Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, this can be the leftover of 3rd party program you uninstalled **if they have problem with uninstaller**. Please think about software you were recently uninstalling.

Action: open toolbars list by right-clicking the taskbar and try to identify weird toolbars and turn them off:

[image]

Comment: @L105 - I'm using my main computer only with software I have tested because many 3rd party developers can cause these issues. For trying new software, I'm using virtual machine which I can throw away if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on your taskbar and disable any toolbars that are activated under the "Tool bars" menu item. Then drag your taskbar by the "dotted" handle as needed and re-enable any tool bars you might want active.

I've experienced this method to solve "weirdness" with the Windows 7 task bar previously, although it's not a guaranteed fix-all solution.

Comment: I posted a new pic to show my problem, the bar was not locked.